# Makefile error#2 when installing freeradius 2.2.8 eap libeap rlm_eap all modules all src all

Tags: ubuntu, freeradius

I'm trying to install freeradius 2.2.8 on Ubuntu 18.04 and when creating the "make" file, i got the following errors:

Do someone know what should i do or install?

```
make[6]: Entering directory '/home/lszima/freeradius-server-release_2_2_8/src/modules/rlm_eap'
Making all in libeap...
make[7]: Entering directory '/home/lszima/freeradius-server-release_2_2_8/src/modules/rlm_eap/libeap'
/home/lszima/freeradius-server-release_2_2_8/libtool --mode=compile --tag=CC gcc -I/home/lszima/freeradius-server-release_2_2_8 -I/home/lszima/freeradius-server-release_2_2_8/src -g -O2 -Wall -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_REENTRANT -D_POSIX_PTHREAD_SEMANTICS -DNDEBUG -I/home/lszima/freeradius-server-release_2_2_8/libltdl -DEAPLIB -I. -I.. -I/home/lszima/freeradius-server-release_2_2_8/src -DOPENSSL_NO_KRB5 -c eap_tls.c
gcc -I/home/lszima/freeradius-server-release_2_2_8 -I/home/lszima/freeradius-server-release_2_2_8/src -g -O2 -Wall -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_REENTRANT -D_POSIX_PTHREAD_SEMANTICS -DNDEBUG -I/home/lszima/freeradius-server-release_2_2_8/libltdl -DEAPLIB -I. -I.. -I/home/lszima/freeradius-server-release_2_2_8/src -DOPENSSL_NO_KRB5 -c eap_tls.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/eap_tls.o
eap_tls.c: In function 'eaptls_success':
eap_tls.c:132:28: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type 'SSL {aka struct ssl_st}'
            tls_session->ssl->session);
                            ^~
Makefile:25: recipe for target 'eap_tls.lo' failed
make[7]: *** [eap_tls.lo] Error 1
make[7]: Leaving directory '/home/lszima/freeradius-server-release_2_2_8/src/modules/rlm_eap/libeap'
Makefile:54: recipe for target 'libeap' failed
make[6]: *** [libeap] Error 2
make[6]: Leaving directory '/home/lszima/freeradius-server-release_2_2_8/src/modules/rlm_eap'
Makefile:37: recipe for target 'rlm_eap' failed
make[5]: *** [rlm_eap] Error 2
make[5]: Leaving directory '/home/lszima/freeradius-server-release_2_2_8/src/modules'
Makefile:12: recipe for target 'all' failed
make[4]: *** [all] Error 2
make[4]: Leaving directory '/home/lszima/freeradius-server-release_2_2_8/src/modules'
Makefile:39: recipe for target 'modules' failed
make[3]: *** [modules] Error 2
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/lszima/freeradius-server-
```

release_2_2_8/src'
    Makefile:14: recipe for target 'all' failed
    make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
    make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/lszima/freeradius-server-release_2_2_8/src'
    Makefile:97: recipe for target 'src' failed
    make[1]: *** [src] Error 2
    make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/lszima/freeradius-server-release_2_2_8'
    Makefile:18: recipe for target 'all' failed
    make: *** [all] Error 2
    lszima@ubuntu-de-01:~/freeradius-server-release_2_2_8$

Answer (score 0):

Freeradius 2.2.8 does not build with the OpenSSL APIs of version 1.1.0 or 1.1.1 or newer. This is documented in https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=828305

As a result of this, if you must use version 2.2.8, you need to use an Ubuntu with older OpenSSL, which means you're going to be falling back to using Ubuntu Xenial 16.04. That's currently the next older supported release of Ubuntu that might have older OpenSSL libraries available to it.

Failing this, however, if it also fails to build there, you will have to use a later version of FreeRADIUS and manually copy your configuration files, etc. over. There does come a point where you cannot avoid 'updating' to newer software versions.

Comment: FreeRADIUS 2.2.8 is completely unsupported at this point.  If you ask questions on the mailing lists or try and purchase commercial support you'll get told to upgrade to v3.0.x.